# Evaluate text containing a named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I **evaluate a text string that contains a named range**?
I tried with EVAL, EVALUATE and INDIRECT with no success.

A bit more..

For another system, I've got 50+ formulas with 200+ variables, an example follows:

```
<ABC>+<DEF>/<TRE-1>
```

To be able to use them all at once in Excel without manually changing every formula, variable and operator, I use a couple (or more) SUBSTITUTE formulas to render a string that Excel might be able to digest:

```
=ABC+DEF/TRE_1
```

I referenced all variables to named ranges. For e.g.:

ABC is cell B2, value 5.4

DEF is cell B3, value 3.2

TRE_1 is cell B4, value 1

But then the I can't get the resulting string evaluated with INDIRECT or EVALUATE. 
It just gives me a #NAME or #REF error, because it seems it doesn't recognize the variable as a named range (and thus a value).

Any ideas?

I don't want to implement this in VBA. I know it's possible using the .RefersTo method..

Answer (score 4):

Try to use this syntax:

`=INDIRECT("ABC")+INDIRECT("DEF")/INDIRECT("TRE_1")`

Pay attention to quotes. It seems that's how `INDIRECT` works: `=INDIRECT("ABC+DEF")` returns `#REF!`

See also this sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxj7cgjmnx8iv0t/INDIRECTwithNamedRegions.xlsx

Comment: This answer should become the accepted answer, the string in INDIRECT is a cell reference, not a formula (as "INDIRECT" stands for "indirect reference"). And the reference does evaluate correctly if it's a named range. `=INDIRECT("NamedRange1")+INDIRECT("NamedRange2")` works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but this is just one of the 50+ formulas I have where I need this to work in a streamlined way, so I can't use several Indirects. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @bb_pt you'd better submit a new one to avoid confusing - answers already submitted won't be edited

Answer (score 0):

INDIRECT dows not evaluate formulas, only references: you need to use Evaluate, but thats only available via the XLM or COM interfaces. 
You can embed Evaluate inside a defined name formula, but often this method is impractical.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA solution (as seen [here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2212496,00.asp) or [here](https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula)) is to setup an UDF(User Defined Function) inside a module in the current workbook as for e.g.:

```
Function Eval(ByVal S As String) As String

Eval = Evaluate(S)

End Function
```

Having the variables setup as named ranges, in a cell enter:

```
 =Eval("ABC+DEF/TRE_1")
```

And it will pop-out the result correctly.

Now.. I don't want to use VBA...

Comment: Just now when implementing it, I noticed it may be useful to add the "Application.Volatile" to the code for the  UDF to be recalculated every time a calculation happens (instead of only when inputting the formula).